# share data between controller actions in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, instance-variables

I'm currently developing an application that needs to parse some (a big file of) csv data. I have to perform several steps to manipulate and map the data to ActiveRecord objects. This has to be done in several steps, and i have to display the results in a view.

So i start at imports#index. Here i let the users upload the csv file, nothing fancy

Then i go trough imports#create to create the import object.

Then i'm at step2 imports#show. Here i display the results. So in import#show i parsed all the csv data and delete the rows that i dont need. (It's one big array with structs in it.)

Then i want to go to step 3 to manipulate the same data further. But how in the world can i get the big array from step2 in step3 without a session (because of the Structs i cant insert it in a session it gives me the following error: `TypeError (can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x105477128>):`

And when i put it in a session with .inspect it raises this error: `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow`. But then it's all one big string and i want to maintain the ruby functionality (e.g. it's 1 big array with struct objects in it...)

So to wrap it all up

Step 1
upload file
Step2
parse data & manipulate it.
Step3
Use the data from step2 (without a session..)
Step4
User data from step3

How in the world can i get this to work... I can't seem to figure it out :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep in mind different principles:

- Controllers are not meant to deal with data, Models or Classes do
- parsing a big file shouldn't be made inside the controller but put inside some queue (Delayed Job handles this properly, see how it works [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job)). Just imagine your user waiting endlessly for something to happen...

To sum up:

- Step 1: upload file => ok I guess you save it, great
- Step2 parse data & manipulate it => should be triggered by step 1 and launched in a Delayed Job queue
- Step3 Use the data from step2 (without a session..) => all data processed the way I suggest could be stored in cache, database or wherever you find it useful
- Step4 User data from step3 => you want to display the result of your processing, I suggest you implement an AJAX request checking if the job was done or not (to do that, I highly recommend you store the info in cache in order not to query your database too often).

Comment: Thanks for your response. And yes i do all the parsing in my models i know that... But what if i save my ([#<struct #<Class:0x1055d8350> name="name", email="email@email.nl">, etc]) in the database, and i will query for it then it all would be a big string right?! How can i manipulate the data further in step3 ?!

Comment: db would not be appropriate if you're manipulating non ActiveRecord objects. What about using cache or simply writing a yml file you could then load as a hash?

Comment: Ah oke, i will look into the cache, so when i do this @instance_var = %w(a b c d e). And when i cache that and i query the cache i can do something like this: @instance_var_with_data_from_cache.shift => ["b", "c", "d", "e"]. I mean do i maintain my ruby functionality ?

Comment: yep, structured data are maintained.

Comment: Ok, thanks i will try it out :) Any recommendations about caching? is it build in or do i have to use gems => memcached as you mentioned?

Comment: There are several cache stores available: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores . There is also Redis which provides persistent data storage (and could be used as cache)

Comment: Yes it does, sorry for the delay. I'll try your solution next thing in the morning :)